# how can I improve the script for screenshots of many urls with puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I state that I am not an expert programmer :), I have been trying for about a month in the development of a script to make screenshots of many urls at a time and save them locally on my computer.

**What I'm going to do in the script is the following:**

1 - I open Url from the **url-list.js** file

2 - I wait for the page to load.

3 - I do a check to see if the button for the consent of privacy exists on my page. If it
exists, click on it and wait for the advertising formats to load.

4 - I make a complete scroll of the page to load all the images.

5 - Save the screenshot on my cpmputer.

6 - Register through an external site how many times the script has been used.

**What happens to me every now and then and I can't understand is the following:**

- Sometimes, I can find the button to accept the coockies on the page even if it exists in the Cookie Array.
- Sometimes the time runs out to find the button to accept the privacy consent and then the script stops.
- Sometimes the script crashes I don't know why ... maybe it saturates the memory?

I kindly ask for your help to understand if I was wrong to write this script or if there is the possibility to improve it in some point. :)

**FILE screenshot.js:**

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const os = require('os');
const username = require('username');

//I identify the operating system and the architect of the CPU to run the Google Chrome Patch
var architetturaCPU = os.arch();
var sistemaOperativo = os.type();
console.log('System OS: '+sistemaOperativo+' '+architetturaCPU);
//console.log(os.platform());
 
// Device width and height - Desktop / Tablet / Mobile
const device_width = 1920;
const device_height = 1080;

//Patch di Chrome
var systemPath = '';
if (sistemaOperativo == 'Darwin'){
    console.log('Chrome for MacOS');
    var systemPath = '/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome';
} else
if(sistemaOperativo == 'Windows_NT' && architetturaCPU == 'x64'){
    console.log('Chrome for Windows 64bit');
    var systemPath = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe';
}else
if(sistemaOperativo == 'Windows_NT' && architetturaCPU == 'x32'){
    console.log('Chrome for Windows 32bit');
    var systemPath = 'C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe';
}else
if(sistemaOperativo == 'Windows_NT' && architetturaCPU == 'ia32'){
    console.log('Chrome for Windows 32bit');
    var systemPath = 'C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe';
}


//I build an Array and insert all the buttons for the consent of the Cookies for the Network sites
const cookie1 = 'button.amecp_button-accetto.iubenda-cs-close-btn';
const cookie2 = 'button.iubenda-cs-accept-btn.iubenda-cs-btn-primary';
var BtnCookie = [
  cookie1, 
  cookie2
];


(async function () {

//I read the url file
var fs = require('fs');
var urlArray = fs.readFileSync('url-list.js').toString().split("\n").filter(a => a);

//Launch Puppeteer
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  headless: true,
  executablePath: systemPath,
  args: ['--disable-dev-shm-usage','--no-sandbox']});


//Loop through all the url-list.js URL
var contaUrl = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < urlArray.length; i++){

//Check if empty spaces are present in the url file list
if (urlArray[i].indexOf("http") != '-1'){    

//I open the boswser, delete the cache and set the page size
const page = await browser.newPage();
const client = await page.target().createCDPSession();
await client.send('Network.clearBrowserCookies');
await client.send('Network.clearBrowserCache');

await page.setCacheEnabled(false);
await page.setViewport({width: device_width, height: device_height});
await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36');

//Tell me which URL you are working on
console.log(' ');
console.log('\x1b[33m%s','Open URL > '+urlArray[i],'\x1b[0m');
console.log(' ');
await page.goto(urlArray[i],{waitUntil:'networkidle2'}); 
await page.waitFor(20000);

//Find the class / id of the button on the page to accept cookies
var contaNumeroValoriBtnCookie = BtnCookie.length;
for(var n = 0; n <= BtnCookie.length; n++){

if (await page.$(BtnCookie[n]) !== null ) {
  
console.log(BtnCookie[n]);
const navigationPromise = page.waitForSelector(BtnCookie[n]);
await page.click(BtnCookie[n]); 
await navigationPromise; 

    console.log('\x1b[32m%s', 'Bypass Cookie... OK!','\x1b[0m');
    break;
    }else if (n == contaNumeroValoriBtnCookie) {
     
        console.log('\x1b[31m%s', 'Cookie not found!','\x1b[0m');
    }else {
    
        //console.log('I'm looking for the cookie...');
    }

} //end - Find the class / id of the button on the page to accept cookies



//Scroll the entire page to load the content
await autoScroll(page);

async function autoScroll(page){
  await page.evaluate(async () => {
      await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          var totalHeight = 0;
          var distance  = 100;
         
          var timer = setInterval(() => {
              var scrollHeight = document.body.scrollHeight;
              window.scrollBy(0, distance);
              totalHeight += distance;

              if(totalHeight >= scrollHeight){
                  clearInterval(timer);
                  resolve();
              }
          }, 300);
      });
  });
}

//Go back to the top of the page
await page.evaluate(_ => {window.scrollTo(0, 0);});

await page.waitFor(10000);

//I clean up the URL before saving the file
var str = urlArray[i];
str = str.replace(/[^\w]+/ig,'-');
var convertiUrl = str;

//SAVE screenshot
await page.screenshot({path: './screenshot/'+convertiUrl+i+'.jpg', fullPage: true});
await page.waitFor(5000);

//Register through an external site, on which url the script is most used
if (contaUrl < urlArray.length){
const urlCeck = new URL(urlArray[i]);
var impressionPage = "https://lab.servername.it/track/index1.php?id=6dfc76542a4817a-368/-/"+urlCeck.hostname+"/-/impressionPage";
await page.goto(impressionPage ,{waitUntil:'load'});
}

contaUrl++;

//I register via an external site, the username that used the script and count how many times the script was used in total
if (contaUrl >= urlArray.length){
var userNameScript = await username();
var impressionNomeUtente = "https://lab.servername.it/track/index1.php?id=5a98b9a86118ae6-288/-/"+userNameScript+"/-/userNameScript";
var impressionScript = "https://lab.servername.it/track/index1.php?id=5a98b9a86118ae6-288/-/script_impression/-/script_impression";
await page.goto(impressionNomeUtente, {waitUntil:'load'});
await page.goto(impressionScript, {waitUntil:'load'});
}

await page.close();

}//end if (urlArray[i].indexOf("http") != '-1'){  
  
}//fine loop

browser.close();

console.log(' ');
console.log('\x1b[32m%s', contaUrl+' all screenshot saved :)','\x1b[0m');
console.log(' ');

})(); //end script
```

Comment: Some of your questions can be answered here, but the format of the question with this massive amount of script is rather a code review request and it has its own platform on Stack Exchange: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ _(OK, it would require an error-free code)_. I suggest - for next time - to share only the relevant code, or a pseudo code version of your script to have a more general appearance, so others can find the question+answers more useful. _"Sometimes the script crashes I don't know why"_ Can you share the error msg about these cases please?

Comment: No problem at all :) **Not yet,** as I put my comment after the url: they expect working code at the Code Review which may require only some small refactoring. So your issue is still better here (I also realized this after commenting). But I hope you feel how the question could be improved. This time if you provide more info about your error msg I can take a look (and hope some strict member of the community won't flag the whole question meantime )

Comment: you've just removed your comment I replied to 

Comment: hi @theDavidBarton, sorry, I was thinking of canceling the question and canceled the comment. so let's do it, as soon as the script returns an error, I add it to the post and leave you a comment! thanks for the support.. :)

Comment: hi @theDavidBarton, why are some screenshots saved with larger size in width? I set a value of 1920px in width ...

Comment: I think when you set `fullPage: true` in `page.screenshot` the `viewPort` that you've set is ovewritten. You could use the `clip` option if you want to crop them to the same size: https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v4.0.0&show=api-pagescreenshotoptions

Comment: what i would like to do is capture a screenshot with fixed width of 1920px and height based on the total content of the page.

Comment: I see. I have no solution for this at the moment. But it is a good topic for a new question. I am sure the community will be able to help in this topic.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216300/discussion-between-carver14-and-thedavidbarton).

Comment: @theDavidBarton, slowly I practically finished writing my first app with nodejs to take screenshots with the puppeteer.  Since you have always supported me and for this I am grateful, would you like to try my app?  obviously if you want and if you have time.  I would be very happy to have your opinion.  :) if it's okay, I'll prepare a zip of the program and send it to you by email.

Comment: I did a code review on your git project, make sure to check your github notifications.